# How do I update a python igraph object with new cluster membership?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, igraph

### How can I update an igraph graph with the results of my clustering method?

I have performed some clustering in Python.

For example, I have an **igraph** graph object:

```
# Generate a graph with 100 nodes and 250 edges.
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(n=100,m=250)
```

I then apply my clustering algorithm. In this case, for example purposes, I just randomly assign each node to cluster 0-3.

```
# Make a random partition of 4 clusters.
from random import randint
partition = [randint(0,3) for x in range(100)]
```

I can generate an igraph clustering object:

```
# Cluster the graph.
clusters = igraph.VertexClustering(g,membership = partition)
```

This enables me to access all the useful methods of this class, for example:

```
clusters.modularity
```

But, I'd like to update the original graph, *g* with the results of my clustering.

```
# Checks.
clusters.membership == partition # True
clusters.graph.clusters().membership == partition # False - I want this to be True.
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Graph.clusters()` method returns a new `VertexClustering` object each time it is called, the clustering is never stored as part of the graph.

If you really need to store the clustering in the graph object, you can always use `setattr`.

```
>>> setattr(g, "clustering", clusters)
>>> clusters.graph.clustering.membership == partition
True
```

If you pickle the object, the clusters will be retained.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dump(g, open("graph.pickle", "wb"))
>>> ng = pickle.load(open("graph.pickle", "rb"))
>>> ng.clustering.membership == partition
True
```